# Google Big table

Tags: google-app-engine

I created one project.i want to use google Big table as my database.

so that i used JPA datastore.I created one JPA program(using eclipse) in that i selected ODBC database.I display lot of option like MySQL etc.. What option i select to interact with Bigtable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you an [use JPA](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/usingjpa.html) with App Engine's data store.  There is no connection to MySQL.